# Print only the inputted value

Tags: html, css

I just want to ask on how to print in pdf style and display only the inputted value not the textbox or the dropdown.

[click this link to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wta1e.png)

I also want to display something like this, but how? I hope anyone can help me, thank you in advance. :)

[click this link to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUDqB.png)

And lastly, here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printWebpage(t) {
            t.style.display = "none";
            window.print();
            t.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ALQUIZA SURVEYING OFFICE</h1>
    <h3>CONTRACTUAL PAYROLL</h3>
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
    <br/><br/>
    Survey: <input type="text" id="survey" name="survey"/>
    <br/><br/>
    Payment:
    <select id="payment" name="payment">
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option>Single</option>
        <option>Double</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
    Team:
    <select id="team" name="team">
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option>Team A</option>
        <option>Team B</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
    <button onclick="printWebpage(this)">Print Webpage</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking for [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@media)?

Comment: yeah! I think. haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this similar question: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/591434/howplustoplushideplusprintplusbuttonplusonplushard

Comment: it is only how to hide the button. and I want also to hide the textbox and the dropdown. only the info.

Comment: Make the same with the textbox and the dropdown that with the button.

Comment: @Poiz. can you help me? haha.

Comment: Hi Francis, if I'm not wrong, your task is get the values and format them in a certain way. So your problem is not just to 'hide' the print button. Maybe you should have a look to send data with a form via POST method. In this way, you will pass the value of inputs, dropdowns, etc. and besides you will format the result as desired. There's a lot of info about POST method. Try it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@media):

```
/* Only applied in print mode */
@media print {
    /* Hide or style your elements here */
    input[type=text] {
        border: none;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

[Here is a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Media), where your use case is explained.